# Distance between 2 user defined georeferenced grids in km

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, distance, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have 2 variables 'Root zone' and 'Tree cover' both are geolocated (NetCDF) (which are basically grids with each grid having a specific value). The values in TC varies from 0 to 100. Each grid size is 0.25 degrees (might be helpful in understanding the distance).

My problem is "I want to calculate the distance of each TC value ranging between 70-100 and 30-70 (so each value of TC value greater than 30 at each lat and lon) from the points where nearest TC ranges between 0-30 (less than 30)."

What I want to do is create a 2-dimensional scatter plot with X-axis denoting the 'distance in km of 70-100 TC (and 30-70 TC) from 0-30 values', Y-axis denoting 'RZS of those 70-100 TC points (and 30-70 TC)'

```py
#I read the files using xarray
deficit_annual = xr.open_dataset('Rootzone_CHIRPS_era5_2000-2015_annual_SA_masked.nc')
tc = xr.open_dataset('Treecover_MODIS_2000-2015_annual_SA_masked.nc')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
## year I am interested in
year = 2000
i = year - 2000
# Select the indices of the low- and high-valued points
# This will results in warnings here because of NaNs;
# the NaNs should be filtered out in the indices, since they will 
# compare to False in all the comparisons, and thus not be 
# indexed by 'low' and 'high'
low = (tc[i,:,:] <= 30)    # Savanna
moderate = (tc[i,:,:] > 30) & (tc[i,:,:] < 70)    #Transitional forest
high = (tc[i,:,:] >= 70)   #Forest
# Get the coordinates for the low- and high-valued points,
# combine and transpose them to be in the correct format
y, x = np.where(low)
low_coords = np.array([x, y]).T
y, x = np.where(high)
high_coords = np.array([x, y]).T
y, x = np.where(moderate)
moderate_coords = np.array([x, y]).T
# We now calculate the distances between *all* low-valued points, and *all* high-valued points.
# This calculation scales as O^2, as does the memory cost (of the output), 
# so be wary when using it with large input sizes.
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist

distances = cdist(low_coords, moderate_coords, 'euclidean')
# Now find the minimum distance along the axis of the high-valued coords, 
# which here is the second axis.
# Since we also want to find values corresponding to those minimum distances, 
# we should use the `argmin` function instead of a normal `min` function.
indices = distances.argmin(axis=1)
mindistances = distances[np.arange(distances.shape[0]), indices]
minrzs = np.array(deficit_annual[i,:,:]).flatten()[indices]

plt.scatter(mindistances*25, minrzs, s = 60, alpha = 0.5, color = 'goldenrod', label = 'Trasitional Forest')

distances = cdist(low_coords, high_coords, 'euclidean')
# Now find the minimum distance along the axis of the high-valued coords, 
# which here is the second axis.
# Since we also want to find values corresponding to those minimum distances, 
# we should use the `argmin` function instead of a normal `min` function.
indices = distances.argmin(axis=1)
mindistances = distances[np.arange(distances.shape[0]), indices]
minrzs = np.array(deficit_annual[i,:,:]).flatten()[indices]

plt.scatter(mindistances*25, minrzs, s = 60, alpha = 1, color = 'green', label = 'Forest')


plt.xlabel('Distance from Savanna (km)', fontsize = '14')
plt.xticks(fontsize = '14')
plt.yticks(fontsize = '14')
plt.ylabel('Rootzone storage capacity (mm/year)', fontsize = '14') 
plt.legend(fontsize = '14')
#plt.ylim((-10, 1100))   
#plt.xlim((0, 30))
```

What I want is to know whether the code seems to have an error (as it is working now, but doesn't seem to work when I increase the 'high = (tc[i,:,:] >= 70 ` to 80 for year 2000. This makes me wonder if the code is correct or not.

Secondly, is it possible to define a 20 km buffer region of 'low = (tc[i,:,:] <= 30)'. What I mean is that the 'low' is defined only when a cluster of Tree cover values are below 30 and not by an individual pixel.

Some netCDF files are attached in the link below:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/unm96q7sfto8y53/AAA7e12bs07XtpMiVFdML_PIa?dl=0

The graph I want is something like this (derived from the code above).[image]

Thank you for your help.